# coxph: length of ’dimnames’ [2] not equal to array extent

Tags: r, knitr

I do some survival analysis using weighted coxph(). I decided to check for Med Center effect and added "+ frailty(CTR_ID)" into the model. The code is below.

```
model <- coxph(Surv(fgstart, fgstop, fgstatus) ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + ... + dummy:Xn + frailty(CTR_ID)),
                data = pdata, weight = fgwt)
```

Where "dummy" is 0 for missed values in Xn and 1 for available values in Xn.
After all computations were done I got the next result.

```
## Error in dimnames(rr) <- list(names(object$residuals), names(object$coefficients)):
length of ’dimnames’ [2] not equal to array extent
```

There were no errors if I run the model without frailty().
I found that I can also use random intercept (1|CTR_ID) to find the frailty effect. I tried this and got all NA's in coef, exp(coef), z and Pr(>|z|) (i.e. in summary(model)). How should I interpret this? Is it correct to use (1|CTR_ID) instead of frailty(CTR_ID)?

**Does anybody know what's wrong and how can I compute the frailty effect? Thank you.**

PS: I do analysis in RStudio with knitr (.Rnw file).

PPS: Images:

[image: str(data)]

[image: summary(data)]

Comment: You should at a minimum offer the results of `str` and `summary` on the datasets (but not the regression objects) involved.

Comment: There are 20 variables (continuous and factors) in the model. What should I look for? Thank you.

Comment: You should try running the model with 3 or 4 of the variables including your dummy and frailty candidate, and see if the same problems arise. If they do then follow the instructions in my first comment. If they don't then run with the next batch of variables. There are many possible pitfalls and I don't think it is fair to ask for an enumeration of the possible sources of error. For that you can do a search on the error message text. An additional point is that Terry Therneau recommends using coxme package rather than frailty terms in coxph.

Comment: The same problems arise. I added 2 images in the post. Thank you.

Comment: Two comments. I don't think using negative times are allowed and I would have expected an ID variable to be factor or character. There's still not enough information to do anything useful at this end. Why not try to make a small dataset that produces the same error?